# Function type with diferent possible types of arguments

Tags: android, function, kotlin, functional-programming

I need to pass some suspend function which will execute retrofit call and return response to other function as a parameter. So my suspend function can have any number of arguments with any types, how can I define it as a functional type to be able to pass it to another function which will invoke it?

```
interface SomeDataSource {
    @GET("some_url")
    suspend fun getObjects(@Path("id") userId: String): Response<A>

    @PUT("some_url")
    suspend fun updateClientFirstName(@Path("id") id: String, @Body requestA: RequestA): Response<Unit>
}
```

```
class SomeRepositoryImpl(private val someDataSource: SomeDataSource) : SomeRepository {
     override suspend fun getObjects(userId: String): List<A>? {
        return baseRequestMaker(params.., true, someDataSource::getObjects)
    }
}
```

```
suspend fun <P, T> baseRequestMaker(params: P, isShowLoader: Boolean = true, request: suspend (input: P) -> Response<T>): T? {
    if (isShowLoader) {
        BaseFragment.apiState.value = Result.Loading
    }
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO + BaseBanqrCoroutineExceptionHandler(CoroutineExceptionHandler)) {
        val apiResponse = request(params)
        val response = apiResponse.body()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + BaseBanqrCoroutineExceptionHandler(CoroutineExceptionHandler)) {
            BaseFragment.apiState.value = Result.Success(response)
        }
        return@withContext response
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my request function parameters can be of any type and count and I can't wrap them into the object because in that case Retrofit annotations  such as `@Path, @Query, @Body`.., will not work.

Comment: Can you provide pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your question is clear enough. However ..

You can do the following.

```
// the method with many arguments
fun methodManyArguments(arg1: String, arg2: Int, arg3: Boolean) {
    println("Calling methodManyArguments($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)")
}

// the method that will pass the many arguments
fun passMethod(method: (arg1: String, arg2: Int, arg3: Boolean) -> Unit) {
    method("arg1", 3, false)
}

// call the passMethod as following
passMethod(::methodManyArguments)
```

The `::` syntax in Kotlin is basically saying "don't invoke" the function now but rather take a function reference to invoke later. Read More [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references)

What I would suggest is to bundle your many arguments into a wrapper class, known as [Parameter Object pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject). Basically it's easier to maintain.

Example with your case will be as following:

```
// the method with many arguments
fun methodInput(input: MethodInput) {
    println("Calling methodInput($input)")
}

// the method that will pass the many arguments as ONE
fun passMethodInput(method: (MethodInput) -> Unit) {
    method(MethodInput("arg4", 6, true))
}

// the data class for the parameter object
data class MethodInput(val arg1: String, val arg2: Int, val arg3: Boolean)

//calling the passMethodInput
passMethodInput(::methodInput)
```

Kotlin Playground Example for a working example [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: Giorgos Neokleous the problem is that my methodManyArguments function arguments is not fixed and I can't wrap them into object because in that case Retrofit annotations will not work, please see the updated question

Comment: @Vahan I will suggest doing the first example, I've provided then